# Error Android: ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity error

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm getting an ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord,Intent) error each time I boot up my program in the debugger. The program won't even start up! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm very new to this environment. Let me know if you need anymore information/code to help me out.

```
01-08 06:01:33.812: D/AndroidRuntime(674): Shutting down VM
01-08 06:01:33.822: W/dalvikvm(674): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{Proyecto.Prueba1/Proyecto.Prueba1.ProyectoActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Proyecto.Prueba1.ProyectoActivity
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Proyecto.Prueba1.ProyectoActivity
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
01-08 06:01:33.892: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you paste the code in your Activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems ProyectoActivity (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) class is not visible for Dalvik. It could be either this class is not compiled (or) not in classpath where dalvik is looking for. Is this your main activity? If so, make sure the package name of this activity is matching with the package name defined in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks, I saw the problem and was in the AndroidManifest.xml, and had not changed the name of the main activity. But now I get this problem


01-08 15:49:19.619: E / AndroidRuntime (584): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can not instantiate class com.prueba.db.ProyectActivity

and no it is due.

greetings and thanks!

Comment: We need complete stack trace. Please post new question with complete stack trace. We will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to figure out if you are importing properly the class, It seems that the debugger can't find it.